# FLAC codec on android 4.1

Tags: android, audio, media, codec

docs for 4.1 state that FLAC codecs are supported. However the mediarecorder.encoder list of codecs does not include FLAC.

If i want to record audio on flac at 16000Mhz so that the output can go direct to ..speech-api calls, i dont know what to do other than record to an intermediate format and then insert an ffmpeg step to get exactly what i need to send to the speech api.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.html

above link has no mention of FLAC.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

above link includes FLAC as core codec on 4.1.

Comment: should i just set the container type = FLAC then use 'default' as the encoder?

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs, for versions up to v4.1, there is a FLAC *decoder* but no FLAC *encoder*.

Comment: good flac codecs in this proj. with jni interfaces    https://github.com/Audioboo/audioboo-android